# Add src/main/resources to classpath when running unit test in eclipse for spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

In eclipse my maven project has a 'src/main/resources/' folder and a 'src/test/resources' folder.  The contents of both directories seem to go into 'Project/target/classes', and the content of just the 'src/test/resources' directory goes into 'Project/target/test-classes'.

When I use spring to load a classpath resource whilst testing, it seems to only have available the stuff that's in 'test-classes' folder on the classpath.  This makes sense, as only testing resources go in the classpath for testing.

However I want my main resources to be available when running unit tests aswell, but they cannot be found when running unit tests as they are not on the classpath.  How do I configure my way around this problem?

Comment: And the appropriate portion of your pom.xml?

Comment: By default surefire adds both classes and test-classes to classpath for test goal execution. There must be something special in your config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the surefire plugin (which is what maven uses to run unit tests) to include any additional classes, jars or resource directories.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html

Comment: This is in lieu of adding your pom.xml excerpt to the question.

Answer (score -1):

When using TestNG to test a project that contains MyBatis, an exception may not be found in the XML file

org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found):

1. Assume that the XML files corresponding to your MyBatis are all placed under src/main/resources/mapper
2. After compilation, the target/classes folder will contain the mapper folder
3. There is no mapper folder in the target/test-classes folder! So the error is reported

Solution
In the pom.xml file, point the Test's resources directory to src/main/resources

```xml
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <!--测试的时候直接读取src/main/resources的资源文件-->
            <testResource>
              <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
```

[Chinese description 中文说明](https://blog.csdn.net/wyyl1/article/details/106007639)

Comment: This question is neither about TestNG, nor mybastis