# Resource folder not on classpath

Tags: eclipse, maven, log4j2

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526772/log4j2-auto-config) about a problem I had, led me to numerous file path changing in order to come up with [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14660613/641586) that caused Maven not not to work properly (apparently Maven is not fond of sub-source-folders).
I changed the project folders to adhere [Maven's standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and put log4j2.xml under *src/main/resources/META-INF* and the problem returned.
For some reason a Folder in eclipse is not on classpath.

How do I make it work?

**EDIT:**
I'm using the latest m2e to manage project's build and packages.
The project (is currently) consists of several sub-projects.
The parent pom defines the different modules and Java's compiler version. The pom of the module containing the META-INF folder, states several dependencies, nothing more.

Comment: Do you have a web app? put your log4j2.xml into *src/main/resources* Are you using m2e in Eclipse (which Eclipse version)? Which Maven version? How does your pom file look like ?

Comment: Most often then not, marking the folder as source folder would fix a issue like yours.

Comment: @khmarbaise I'ts not a web-app + watch EDIT for your other questions. Making META-INF a source folder causes problems with maven (and it's just wrong)

Comment: The questions is why do you need the META-INF folder ? Let Maven generate it.

Comment: I'm not an expert when it comes to maven. As far as I can see, m2e creates META-INF folder within the target/classes folder but the xml files is copied to target/classes and not target/classes/META-INF unless I put the file under the resources/META-INF folder that I created

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add src/main/resources to classpath when running unit test in eclipse for spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820933/add-src-main-resources-to-classpath-when-running-unit-test-in-eclipse-for-spring)

Answer (score 1):

rightclick on your project -> add source folder -> select your resourcefolder. done.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind... resource folder should be on classpath with no need for any operations

Comment: Works perfectly for me, especially because not all my project come initialized with a `resources` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in Eclipse Oxygen.3a is to right-click on the folder -> Build Path -> Use as Source Folder.